# Fixing Table rows/columns

Tags: html, forms, html-table

[image: See this image]

My question is the following I have table in which I am making a request form with a table inside. When I add First Name and Surname everything is okey but when I add the second row and try to expand the Email text field it pushes the Surname as shown in the image above. Can you help me fix it how do I expand the Email all the way without pushing the Surname.

Comment: ok what do you mean by push the surname? are you using html tab ? are you using full CSS ? could you share more element like sample from your code to help us  to analyze ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the second row as spanning two columns... so add colspan="2" in your email td.

```
<td colspan="2">
```

Comment: Actually 5 minuntes ago I did just that thank you for the fasst reaction though.